# Replace substring but not if between tags or in tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, parsing, replace

So I have written this code here:

```
highlighter: function (item) {
    var parts = this.query.split(" ");
    var length = parts.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if(parts[i] != ""){
            item = item.replace(new RegExp('(' + parts[i] + ')', 'ig'), function ($1, match) {
                return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>'
            })
        }
    }

  return item;
}
```

What it does is:

- I have the string `item`, and the string `this.query`
- I split `this.query` at each space, and put the resulting substrings into `parts[]`

My goal is to make every occurrence of a substring from `parts[]` in `item` bold.

So if

```
item = "This is some text"
```

and

```
this.query = "This some"
```

I want `<strong>This</strong> is <strong>some</strong> text`.

This works perfectly, except when I get matches in the `<strong>` element itself. So I want only the matches replaced that aren't in the `strong` tag itself. Because I get resulting strings with `ong>` or `trong>`in it.  Is this possible?

Comment: Note that your first two lines can and should be combined into one: `var parts = this.query.split(" ")`. There's no point constructing an array only to discard it immediately.

Comment: Yeah that seems quite obvious. Don't know why I didn't, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid the strong tags, do the replacement all in one step:

```
item = item.replace(
    new RegExp(parts.join('|'), 'ig'),
    function (match) {
        return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>'
    }
)
```

You'll still have a problem if "item" contains strong before you begin, but otherwise you won't have a problem.

#### Edit:

Let's say you want to match "this", "that" and, "the other". A *regular expression*, or `RegExp` for that is `This|some|the other`. Oddly enough, the string passed to `new RegExp` is parsed as a regular exrpession.

The other important thing to note is that `item.replace(regex, callback)` will replace *every* match it finds with the result of calling `callback(match, ...)` for each one. The first argument passed to callback is the entire match of the regex, while the remaining arguments are the groups within the match.

If you want to know more, read up on regular expressions.

Comment: Works like a charm! Could you explain your answer a bit? It places a | between all the substrings which results in replacing them with their strong equivalent, but what does the | actually mean? and what are the parameters (_,match)? I think _ is probably a wildcard. But why does it need to be a wildcard. And why does it give all the matches to match.

Comment: `_` has no special meaning. It's an argument name typically used for arguments that aren't used.

Comment: @gl3nn This works reliably only if there are not already tags in `item` and if the words to be highlighted do not contain `RegExp`-special characters. For all other cases, see my solution.

Comment: Since the items will just be names this solution works fine. From the moment I have enough reputation I will vote both answers up.

Comment: Another problem. &eacute;. if eac is used as query string, eac becomes strong, and $eacute; doesn't become é anymore. And also i can't use é to search on &eacute;. And i can't find htmlentities encode and decode for javascript...

Comment: @gl3nn [There is no "javascript"](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix). You could build a codec for HTML character entity references with `Object` instances rather easily. However, you are better off if you don't replace text in the HTML markup but in the text node values (as jfriend00 suggested); in parsed text nodes those entity references are already decoded. [DOM 3 XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPath) comes in handy here, and document tree traversal ([DOM 2 Traversal and Range](http://www.barklund.org/blog/2009/09/08/implementors-dom-2-traversal-and-range/) or otherwise) as fallback.

Comment: Found it! Adding the anwser (as an answer, not an edit) if you are interested in my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Because in these languages there is no native negative lookbehind, if you want to *ignore* tags when *replacing*, you need to *match* them and *replace them with themselves*, like so:

```
item = item.replace(
  new RegExp(
    "(<\\/?\\w+(\\s+\\w+(\\s*=\\s*(\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|\\S+))?)*>)"
      + "|(" + parts.join("|") + ")",
    "ig"),
  function (match, tag, p2, p3, attributeValue, matchedText) {
    if (tag)
    {
      return tag;
    }

    return "<strong>" + matchedText + "<\/strong>";
  });
```

(no loop necessary)

Be aware that `\w+` is only an approximation for the characters that are allowed in an element type name or attribute name, and that `\s` is only an approximation for markup white-space.

You might also have to escape your search words if you use them as string arguments to the `RegExp` constructor. For that and if you are confused by the number of necessary escape sequences here, see [JSX:regexp.js](http://PointedEars.de/scripts/regexp.js), where the `String.prototype.regExpEscape()` and `RegExp.prototype.concat()` methods should come in handy, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

To search only outside the tags, you need a parser that can filter out all the HTML tags and present you with only pieces of text between tags that you can search.  I don't know how your particular application works, but often the best place to get a parser is to let the browser parse the HTML for you and do searches only on the resulting textnodes that it has between the tags.

Comment: I'm updating my question with an extra question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used ! :

```
highlighter: function (item) {
    var parts = this.query.replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/^\s|\s$/g,"").split(/\s/);
    if( item.match(/(?:&[^;]*;)+/) != null){
        item = strip(item);
    }
    item = item.replace(
        new RegExp('(' + parts.join('|') + ')', 'ig'),
        function (_, match) {
            return '<strong>' + match + '</strong>'
        }
    )
    return item;
}
```

This is what I turned the function into.
The first line is to get rid of spaces at the end and of sequence of spaces.
This was needed to do a correct split, else the highlighter would highlight all the spaces. ( Which you could only see if you watched the HTML).
Next I check if any special characters were in the item.
If so i strip them using this function :

```
function strip(html)
{
    var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
    tmp.innerHTML = html;
    return tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
}
```

Then I do the replacing part, where I used the code of Eric.

Thanks a lot!
I also got to know regex a bit better!

Comment: Good thinking about `innerHTML`, but remember that it is still a proprietary property, error-prone, and that re-parsing is rather inefficient when compared to using existing text node values directly. I have made some performance optimizations, though.

Comment: What kind of optimizations ? Feel free to enlighten me :D